# LWJGL rendering nothing

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, rendering, lwjgl

I've looked over the following program over and over and cannot find why nothing renders to the screen when I run it:

Game.java:

```
public class Game {

    private int fbid, fbid2;

    public void start(){
        DisplayManager.init();

        glViewport(0, 0, DisplayManager.SCR_WIDTH, DisplayManager.SCR_HEIGHT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 0, DisplayManager.SCR_WIDTH, DisplayManager.SCR_HEIGHT, 1, -1);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        FloatBuffer fb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(6);
        fb.put(100).put(100).put(100).put(200).put(200).put(200);
        fb.flip();

        fbid = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fbid);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fb, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        FloatBuffer fb2 = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
        fb2.put(1).put(1).put(1).put(1).put(1).put(1).put(1).put(1).put(1);
        fb2.flip();

        fbid2 = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fbid2);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fb2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        while(!DisplayManager.shouldClose()){
            render();
        }

        DisplayManager.destroy();
    }

    public void render(){
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fbid);
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fbid2);
        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        DisplayManager.update();
    }

}
```

DisplayManager.java:

```
public class DisplayManager {

    public static final int SCR_WIDTH = 640;
    public static final int SCR_HEIGHT = 480;

    public static final int FPS = 30;

    public static void init(){
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT));
            Display.setTitle("StepBattler");
            Display.setResizable(false);
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void update(){
        Display.update();
        Display.sync(FPS);
    }

    public static void destroy(){
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static boolean shouldClose(){
        return Display.isCloseRequested();
    }

    public static boolean shouldResize(){
        return Display.wasResized();
    }

}
```

When I run the screen, I just get a window filled with black, and I cannot understand why a white triangle won't render to the window. I've messed around with `glClearColor()`, and changing its values does succeed in changing the window background color, but I can't make a white triangle appear in the window. Also, I tried using `glBegin()...glEnd()` to render in immediate mode, with none of the code having to do with buffers in there, and it still didn't render anything. I'm really confused about this, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments in you `glOrtho()` call look to be in the wrong order:

```
glOrtho(0, 0, DisplayManager.SCR_WIDTH, DisplayManager.SCR_HEIGHT, 1, -1);
```

The signature of `glOrtho()`, based on the [man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml), is:

```
void glOrtho(GLdouble left, GLdouble right,
             GLdouble bottom, GLdouble top,
             GLdouble nearVal,  GLdouble farVal);
```

Since you're passing `0` for both *left* and *right*, the result would be an invalid projection matrix.

The correct call for your case is:

```
glOrtho(0, DisplayManager.SCR_WIDTH, 0, DisplayManager.SCR_HEIGHT, 1, -1);
```